# Draw a line between points on a MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to draw a line that follows the coordinates given to me from a KML file.  I tried using a couple KML parsers, but none of them seemed to work so I'm manually parsing the data.  You can view the KML file that I am using in this question [here](http://ianspence.com/api/translink/016.kml).

I am able to get the coordinates and verified them to be correct by adding them as Annotations.  It looks like this:

[image: Points on a map]

So I've looked at a few examples of making polylines, but I can't figure it out.  Looking at [this](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-draw-an-mkpolyline-on-a-map-view/) tutorial, I tried this:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    for (NSDictionary * c in points) {
        double x = [[c valueForKey:@"x"] doubleValue];
        double y = [[c valueForKey:@"y"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = y;
        coordinate.longitude     = x;
        MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinate count:points.count];
    }
}
```

`points` is an NSArray that contains NSDictionaries of just a *x* and *y* key with the coordinates.

However, xcode gives me an error saying:

> Sending 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D *'; take the address with &

If I try adding a & before `coordinate` it gives my a *BAD_ACCESS* fault when running.

I'm hoping there is a easier way of doing this, and that one of you can help me make some sense of this.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution to my problem but am still working on it.  Please still do answer/comment, but I will post my solution if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polylineWithCoordinates` method expects a pointer to a C *array* of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs.

When you put just `coordinate` which is a single `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, the compiler gives that warning.

When you put `&coordinate` to send a pointer, the compiler warning goes away but `coordinate` itself is still a single `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct.  At run-time, the method assumes that the pointer you gave it points to an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs, tries to interpret the contents of memory *after* the single `coordinate` (which you have not allocated) which results in the "bad access".

In the `for` loop, you need to add all the coordinates in the `points` `NSArray` to a C array which you allocate before the loop.  *After* the loop and after the C array is ready with all the coordinates, *then* you create the polyline and add it to the map view.  For example:

```
//Declare C array big enough to hold the number of coordinates in points...
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[points.count];

int coordinatesIndex = 0;

for (NSDictionary * c in points) {
    double x = [[c valueForKey:@"x"] doubleValue];
    double y = [[c valueForKey:@"y"] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = y;
    coordinate.longitude = x;

    //Put this coordinate in the C array...     
    coordinates[coordinatesIndex] = coordinate;

    coordinatesIndex++;
}

//C array is ready, create the polyline...
MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:points.count];

//Add the polyline to the map...
[self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
```

Don't forget to implement the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method:

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *pr = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        pr.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        pr.lineWidth = 5;
        return pr;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anna.  Thank you for your answer.  Now I've got to figure out why the line is looping back from the end to the beginning.

Comment: That can happen if the last point has the same coordinates as the first point.